# SQL join query about 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have a table A

```
Trade#    Trade_DT
  1        08/10/2013
  2        08/20/2013
```

and table B

```
BaseRate   EffectiveDT
  1.5       08/01/2013
  2.0       08/15/2013
  3.0       08/25/2013
```

I want to have a join such that i get the EffectiveDT after the TradeDT

```
Trade# Trade_DT   BaseRate    EffectiveDT
  1    08/10/2013  2.0        08/15/2013
  2    08/20/2013  3.0        08/25/2013
```

Comment: Can someone correct the table format?

Comment: you can use the code format button or Ctrl+K to format your text. I just did it

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL Flavor)?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want the *earliest* effective date after the `Trade_Dt`.  The following will work in any SQL dialect:

```
select a.*,
       (select min(EffectiveDt)
        from b
        where b.EffectiveDt > a.TradeDt
       ) as EffectiveDt
from a;
```

EDIT:

To get all the values from the `b` table requires just joining the table back in:

```
select t.Trade#, t.Trade_DT, b.BaseRate, b.EffectiveDt
from (select a.*,
             (select min(EffectiveDt)
              from b
              where b.EffectiveDt > a.TradeDt
             ) as EffectiveDt
      from a
     ) t join
     b
     on a.EffectiveDt = b.EffectiveDt;
```

Comment: there is no base rate returned with your query

Answer (score 0):

in Oracle you can use this:

```
  select distinct Trade,
           Trade_DT,
           FIRST_VALUE(BaseRate) Over (partition by Trade order by EffectiveDT desc) BaseRate,
           FIRST_VALUE(EffectiveDT) Over (partition by Trade order by EffectiveDT desc) EffectiveDT
      from tableA
inner join tableB 
        on tableA.Trade_DT >= tableB.EffectiveDT
```

And here a [demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d283/9).

Answer (score 0):

This code uses only standard SQL:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.EffectiveDT =  
                 (SELECT MIN(EffectiveDT) 
                  FROM TableB b1 
                  WHERE a.TradeDT < b1.EffectiveDT)
```